# What's wrong with this script?

Tags: bash

```
find /abc/companies/ -name 'ABC141*.csv' | while read fname
do
   sftp ABC141@servername <<EOF
   cd ../ABC141_01/
   put $fname
   quit
   EOF
   mv $fname ./archive/$(basename $fname)-$(date +%Y%m%d-%T)
done
```

I have tried using scp command and it doesn't work. I am using passwordless login ssh keys.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very informative. Please post error messages, log entries and specific ways it deviates from expectations.

Comment: It is giving me syntax error on line 20 saying unexpected end of file. And I don't have 20 lines in script even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the indentation shown in your question is the same as that in your actual script file, then that is likely your problem. Your `EOF` needs to be at the beginning of the line or you can use `<<-EOF` and that will allow you to indent the closing `EOF` *but only using tabs* - not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ABC141 connecting with a public/private key? If not, then `sftp` is waiting for a password when you're trying to pass it commands. Simply install a public key into `servername:~ABC141/.ssh/authorized_keys` and the private key into `~/.ssh/id_dsa` or `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and then `sftp` should connect cleanly without waiting for a password to be entered.

Comment: Yes, I am using keys. When I just try to connect through normal terminal, it works. But my script is not getting executed.